# What am I doing wrong regarding flipping omlettes or pancakes?

Tags: omelette

It seems that whenever I need to flip an omelette, either the top is way too liquid (thus, I can't flip it effectively, as it just runs off the top); or by the time the top solidifies, the bottom is over-cooked if not charred.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong but not sure what (aside from using way less so the omelette is much thinner and cooks through faster - mine are ~1.5cm thick).

*(the question is primarily about omelettes but I had similar issues with large pancakes with more liquidy batter)*.

Comment: This has already been answered a couple times on SA, most notably here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/how-to-succeed-with-making-omelette/4481#4481

Comment: Lower heat should help prevent the bottom from burning while the top is still setting.